# Why is the inner loop for parsing the line I read being skipped every other iteration through the outter reading loop?

Tags: c++, file-io, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{;
    int arraylen = 7, arraylen_new = 0, i = 0, nextstep = 0;
    string line, field, junkText;
    string* randNum = new string[arraylen];
    string* phrase = new string[arraylen];

    ifstream randomTxt;
    arraylen = 5;

    randomTxt.open("random.txt");

    while(!randomTxt.eof())
    {
        getline(randomTxt,line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        nextstep = 0;
        while(getline(ss,field,','))
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            /*if(nextstep == 0)
            {
                randNum[i] = field;
                cout<< "number " << i << ": " << randNum[i] << endl;
                nextstep = 1;
            }

            else if(nextstep == 1)
            {
                junkText = field;
                cout<< "junk " << i << ": " << junkText << endl;
                nextstep = 2;               
            }
            else
            {
                items[i] = field;
                cout<< "items " << i << ": " << items[i] << endl;
            }*/

            if(i == (arraylen-1))
            {
                arraylen_new = arraylen + 1;
                string* temp1 = new string[arraylen_new];
                string* temp2 = new string[arraylen_new];
                copy(randNum, (randNum+arraylen), temp1);
                delete [] randNum;
                randNum = temp1;

                copy(phrase, (phrase + arraylen), temp2);
                delete [] phrase;
                phrase = temp2;
                arraylen = arraylen_new;
            }
        }
        cout<<"test"<<endl;
        i++;

    }    
    randomTxt.close();

    /*for(int i = 0; i < arraylen;i++)
    {
        cout<< "UPC " << i << ": " << UPC[i] << "\t" << "Phrase " << i << ": " << phrase[i] << endl;

    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

When checking the value for `i` the print out is as follows:

```
0
0
0
test
test
2
2
2
test
test
4
4
4
```

And so on until my file is read completely. My iteration needs to match up properly because I use it to save each piece of the line into separate arrays. Any ideas why it seems to skip the inner while loop?

Here is a snippet of the text file:

```
333331234567,blah,"this is nonsense"
222221234567,word,"yadda yadda words"
111111234567,thing,"total gibberish stuff"
```

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok my post was edited to include the code in the link. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: After fixing a lot of wrong statements (but no logic), your code works for me correctly. Are you sure that is the correct code and text file?

Comment: Free advice: get a modern C++ book that talks about RAII, and forget about `string* randNum = new string[arraylen]`. replace with `std::vector<std::string> randNum(arraylen)`, you will save yourself lots of time.

Comment: I am restricted to arrays so no vectors.

Comment: @StenSoft I d not think its the file but can not say for sure. The idea is read each line, parse at the comma, and save each piece to their corresponding array/throw away string.

Comment: Arrays, great! Then, as the sizes are const, declare them as so, and switch to `std::array<std::string,arraylen> randNum;` ! No more ugly `delete[]`...

Comment: [This doesn't come close to compiling](https://ideone.com/dFD0IT). Please also remove any comments that do not add information so that we are left with a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't reproduce your issue.

But I had to fix some names in your sample code, so maybe I accidentally fixed it?

Here's my version, with some additional DEBUG print statements.

Also note that checking for `eof()` is *rarely* useful, so changed the outer loop to `while (getline(randomTxt, line))`.

Then with the `i` loop index, it's more natural to write as a for loop, I think.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5cbde812e0ddf6b)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

/// returns: new array length

int main() {
    size_t arraylen = 7;
    std::string line;
    std::string *randNum = new std::string[arraylen];
    std::string *phrase  = new std::string[arraylen];

    std::ifstream randomTxt;

    randomTxt.open("random.txt");

    for (size_t i=0; getline(randomTxt, line); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "DEBUG LINE: '" << line << "'\n";
        //nextstep = 0;

        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::string field;
        while (getline(ss, field, ',')) {
            std::cout << "DEBUG INNER " << i << " '" << field << "'\n";

            if (i == (arraylen - 1)) {
                size_t arraylen_new = arraylen + 1;
                {
                    std::string *tmp = new std::string[arraylen_new];
                    copy(randNum, randNum + arraylen, tmp);
                    delete[] randNum;
                    randNum = tmp;
                }

                {
                    std::string *tmp = new std::string[arraylen_new];
                    copy(phrase, (phrase + arraylen), tmp);
                    delete[] phrase;
                    phrase = tmp;
                }
                arraylen = arraylen_new;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
DEBUG LINE: '333331234567,blah,"this is nonsense"'
DEBUG INNER 0 '333331234567'
DEBUG INNER 0 'blah'
DEBUG INNER 0 '"this is nonsense"'
DEBUG LINE: '222221234567,word,"yadda yadda words"'
DEBUG INNER 1 '222221234567'
DEBUG INNER 1 'word'
DEBUG INNER 1 '"yadda yadda words"'
DEBUG LINE: '111111234567,thing,"total gibberish stuff"'
DEBUG INNER 2 '111111234567'
DEBUG INNER 2 'thing'
DEBUG INNER 2 '"total gibberish stuff"'
```

Notes

- you may want make a `grow_array` function because you duplicated that code
- you may want to grow by factor instead of 1 element at a time; this won't scale at all and lead to abysmal performance/heap fragmentation

Comment: Thank you for this I will check it out in later today. Also I plan on making a function like you suggested this is just a "rough draft" of my project. Once I get this working I will separate it into its own function.

Comment: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5cbde812e0ddf6b) (fixed link)

Comment: I tried it with the for loop and had the same issue. Could there be a problem in the commented section I have where I save each piece of the parsed line to separate arrays?

Comment: No there couldn't because comments don't get executed. Also, you claim the inner loop isn't being run, so that would mean this code is skipped even if not commented (**PRO TIP**: share the _actual_ code. It's annoying waste of time for us to guess)

Comment: I edited my code to make sure it runs as is. If you take it right now and run it the output should show the duplication issue I am having. Even changes to the while loop to for loop has the same issue.

Comment: Huh. Duplication? That's the first time you mention it. You said inner loop was being skipped

Comment: I _think_ I get your point now. Your problem is really that you're using `eof()` in the wrong way. `eof()` is only true _after_ trying to read past-the-end.

Comment: Here's with the DEBUG messages (**use** that. Debug your own problems!) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a34e5c2c15fa3162)**. You see, you get the `DEBUG OUTER` repeated with an empty at the end. Of course, then `randomTxt` is not `.good()` anymore (it's `.eof()`) so the inner loop gets skipped.

Comment: See ***[Why is `eof()` inside a loop condition considered wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)***